# NetBeans project JAR won't run after clean and build?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Inside one of my Netbeans projects, as jar is built and run perfectly.
However, when the same project is cleaned & built, the `lib` folder is absent from `dist` 
and the generated `jar` does not run and produces the following CMD prompt message:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    C:\Windows\system32>CD C:\Users\gurukripa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\I-ROOM\dist


    C:\Users\gurukripa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\I-ROOM\dist>java -jar iroom.jAR
    Unable to access jarfile iroom.jAR

    C:\Users\gurukripa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\I-ROOM\dist>java -jar I-ROOM.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: i/room/Essent
    ials (Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:12
    3)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)

    C:\Users\gurukripa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\I-ROOM\dist>
```

I am using:

- Netbeans 7.0,
- JDK 1.7.0_02,
- JRE 7
- Windows 7 32-bit Home Premium

When I double-click on the jar nothing happens, but I can see `javaaw` is running in task manager. Is there a valid reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your JAR was compiled with a different version of the JDK than the one you are trying to use to run it. Ensure that both Netbeans and command line are using the same version of the JDK.

Comment: how?? netbeans is using jdk 1.7(default) as shown in library & in control panel i have only have jre 7 u2 and jdk 7 u2 (ie jdk 1.7.0_02)

Comment: @user1411656 - Are you sure there is only one version of Java installed on your system?